# Add printer Epson L110

Tags: drivers, printing, kubuntu

I have been using kubuntu 13.10 now,. but I have problem,.

when I have installed driver epson L110 on my kubuntu
I dont know how to print on my kubuntu,. i cant printer device in my kubuntu)

can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=SG&CTI=4&PRN=L350%20Series&OSC=LX)

Choose your package and arch. and install